# what is the point of being XHTML compliant?

Tags: xhtml

All modern browsers understand HTML, so what is the point of being XHTML compliant other then writing more characters found on the far right side of the keyboard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no point that I can think of. The W3C has canceled XHTML 2.0, although there is supposed to be an XHTML5, which I guess is HTML5 for masochists. Originally XHTML was going to lead us into the world of "correct" HTML documents, but it generated as many (or more) problems than it ever solved.

We validate against either HTML 4.01 Transitional or HTML5 (to the degree that you can do that). That plus clean CSS gives you about the best you can shoot for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problems it created? What's wrong sticking to standards? Without standards you wouldn't be able to connect almost any screen to your computer etc etc ... we use standards to describe all kinds of things and syntax is even used in natural language, so what's the problem?

Comment: @STATUS: I'm a huge fan of standards that actually accomplish something. The primary problem it caused was confusing people about what problem it was solving. They felt like they had to rewrite their docs, but they didn't know why.

Comment: @Peter: wasn't the idea to have stricter parsing to make it easier to write parsers in the first place? Of course you're still left with legacies that you'd have to support as a browser vendor, but in general the idea seemed pretty clear to me: well formed (XML-based) markup.

Comment: @STATUS: Yes, but any solution has to be considered in the context of "what problem does this solve, and for whom?" XHTML didn't solve the problem for the browser vendors because of all of the old, crufty HTML out there. It didn't solve any problems for designers because it gave them almost nothing new in terms of design possibilities, but it *did* saddle them with rigid syntax rules. As programmers we're used to stuff like that, but I've met designers who have almost no left brain at all (just like I have almost no right brain :-).

Comment: Why don't we validate to HTML 4.01 Strict (instead of Transitional)?

Comment: @Peter: fair point. As I wrote before, I see the burden of the legacy HTML pages, but if everyone goes by "XHTML is just extra effort" that burden will never go away for browser vendors. Once upon a time people thought IE would have to be considered always because of its market share and its quirks that did set it apart from other browsers in those days. But now IE6 is being retired officially by MS (the IE6 countdown) and we see that even MS started to care about standards after IE6. Doesn't that mean that creators of websites should care as well?

Comment: @mc10: I think you should pick one you and you colleagues like, and stick with it. You want to validate against 4.01 Strict, do it. You find Transitional more to your liking, works for me. It's not that I don't care about this, only that I care more about good design, semantic HTML, and clean CSS. After 38+ years in the business, I am much more concerned about the usability and maintainability of the final product than I am about whatever the *standard du jour* is. Even the W3C eventually figured out they were doing an awful lot of navel gazing and that people were starting to ignore them.

Answer (score 5):

XHTML was originally supposed to be a "next generation of HTML", as well as a stricter version of HTML (which would cause failures if any error showed up in the page).  Due to a variety of loopholes and any number of other issues with XHTML (such as pages serving up the wrong mimetype), hardly any pages are actually XHTML, they're just HTML with some extra characters.

Eventually, HTML5 was proposed, w3c split into two groups, then the people working on XHTML 2.0 switched to something better (HTML5) and now everyone is talking about HTML5 taking over everything.

For a longer version (with far more detail), check out this chapter from Dive Into HTML5: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/past.html

Comment: are you saying that if my page validates fine it still is not XHTML? There are loads of pages out there, including a lot of CMS and blog systems and forum systems that promise to create proper XHTML 1.0 or 1.1 strict. And actually some of them do.

Comment: @STATUS: according to the site I linked, if you're not serving up the page with `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type, then it will be parsed by the browser as HTML, regardless of doctype or anything else.  This was a result of the loophole in XHTML 1.0, and was closed in XHTML 1.1 and the never released 2.0.  So even if the syntax is correct XHTML, browsers will ignore that and parse the document as HTML, so the benefit of XHTML is thus removed.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. You'll get a +1 on your answer for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/xhtml.html, one of the reasons XHTML was created was:

> to add the XML ability to extend the language through namespaces. This will make it possible for an author to express more structures and richer semantics than is possible with HTML today. In effect XHTML inherits the possibility of supporting more than one language — instead of extending HTML in a monolithic fashion, XHTML can be extended through modules, where each module define a specific subset of the language.
>
> This, theoretically, means extension of the language can be done without the need for a browser upgrade.

> XHTML is meant to make the use of XML–based languages in end–user applications such as browsers easy, but can also be used for various data processing and storage purposes in situations where the web is only one of several channels. XHTML take advantage of the extensibility of XML to support multiple namespaces and through them languages.

That article also notes that for most people this won't be useful:

> **Recommendations**
> If you don’t have any specific need to deliver XML–based structures to the client, e.g. due to mixing namespaces such as having MathML content in your pages, using Ruby (XHTML 1.1) or techniques such as ACCESS (XHTML 1.2) then consider whether you won’t be better off simply by using HTML 4.01 Strict.

**Edit with additional thoughts:**

I forgot to mention the point I popped in here to bring up too - XHTML can be more easily manipulated into other languages using XSL transforms.